# Is there any way to beat The Universe?

Tags: speed-warp

I beat The Game, and I'm wondering if there's a way to beat the Death Duel opponent that comes after it: The Universe. It has infinite? Hp, and it never attacks. Is there some sort of secret trick so I can defeat it?

Answer (score 2):

When you're playing the universe, you can move in a few more directions than you could before, namely up and down (using the up and down arrow keys).

> To beat the universe, simply destroy all of the stars. This can be done with your weapon or ranged attacks.